# Failed to echo on the same line after using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am reading a text file with the following code and I want to echo the output on the same line on screen. Preceding to that, I want to do some trimming with `sed` but at the end I failed to echo the output on the same line.

```
while read line; do {
     var="$(echo $line | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g')";
     echo -n "$var"
} done < file.txt
```

So if I `echo -n "$line"` it prints the output on the same line but when `sed' comes in it failed to do so. What is it that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Can you show us example input and output?

Comment: Also the `{` and `}` are not necessary there (and are not part of loop syntax).

Comment: It is really funny. I copy the content of the file I was using and paste it to another file and the code works! Also the file sizes differ from each other though having the same content. I don't understand this.

Comment: DOS line endings probably.

Comment: btw, `dos2unix` can be used to convert DOS line endings to Unix line endings